# I want to use named parameters in Dart for clarity. How should I handle them?

Tags: dart, flutter, required, named-parameters

TL;DR: Named parameters are optional as a result of [a conscious design choice](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/4188). Short of having official language support, is there any way to enforce (and inform) required named arguments?

---

I find it extremely useful to use named parameters when defining a class. Take, for instance, an `Ability` in an MMORPG:

```
class Ability {

  final name;
  final effectDuration;
  final recast;            // wait time until next use
  // ...
}
```

`effectDuration` and `recast` both carry the same type of information (i.e. duration of time) and are likely represented by the same datatype. It is easy to mix up which number goes where. However, they are both information vital to the correctness of the object, so they can't be missing during instantiation.

I could just break the program via a try-catch to enforce the requirement of those parameters, but that doesn't sound like fun for someone who uses the class and has no idea (short of reading the docs and understanding intuitively what the class does) that they are required.

Is there any way to enforce the requirement of certain named parameters while managing to inform the caller of said requirement and/or help them use it correctly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [meta](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta) package provides a `@required` annotation that is supported by the DartAnalyzer.

Flutter uses this a lot and provides `@required` directly from `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'`

```
foo({@required String name}) {...}

foo(); // results in static warning
```

`@required` doesn't check if the passed value is `null` or not, only that a value was actually passed on the call site.
To check for `null` you can also use `assert()` to check for passed values

```
class Ability {
  Ability(this.name, this.effectDuration, this.recast) : assert(name != null), assert(effectDuration != null), assert(recast != null);
  final name;
  final effectDuration;
  final recast;            // wait time until next use
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth adding that flutter has a different parameters convention : always use named parameters.

Comment: I also expect the Dart team to change how parameters work after Dart 2.

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: asserts solution does not work for me in NULL SAFETY. Any suggestion? Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

### [Update] New as-of Dart 2.0

In dart 2.0 the `required` keyword has been added to the language as part of the null-safety update. This means that you get a compiler-enforced non-null value rather than one checked by the analyzer; this makes the null check completely redundant.

This means that this code does effectively the same as the old code below, except that you never have to worry about the assertion throwing as the values for `name`, `effectDuration`, and `recast` *cannot* be null.

```dart
class Ability {
  final String name;
  final Duration effectDuration;
  final bool recast;
  final String? description;

  Ability({
    required this.name,
    this.effectDuration = Duration(seconds: 1),
    this.recast = false,
    this.description,
  });
}
```

### Before Dart 2.0

Yes, there is!

Here's an example:

```
class Ability {
  final String name;
  final Duration effectDuration;
  final bool recast;
  final String description;

  Ability({
    @required this.name,
    this.effectDuration = new Duration(seconds: 1),
    this.recast = false,
    this.description,
  }): 
    assert(name != null),
    assert(effectDuration != null);
}
```

You don't have to assert that name is not equal to null, but it might be useful for you.

Comment: The `assert`s act as a run-time fail-safe, right? Ideally the `@required` annotation should throw some warning at the user when they invoke the constructor incorrectly. Neat, thanks!

Comment: At compile time it will throw an error if you don't pass a `name:something`, but it can't know if `something` is null. The assert does that at runtime, but only for debug builds (so it won't slow your production build down!)

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: this solution does not work in NULL SAFATY

Comment: @Kamlesh I've updated the example for null-safety. That doesn't seem right; there must be something else going on in your code as what you've posted compiles just fine for me. I would suggest opening a new question with a more complete 
 code example (and ideally reproducible in DartPad) rather than commenting on a question from 2 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

Although you could use the flutter `foundation` package as described in the accepted answer, when I am working with model classes that don't need to know about Flutter, I prefer to use the [meta](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) package directly. That way it doesn't create an unnecessary dependency on the framework. This allows you to share the Dart code even outside of Flutter.

Add [meta](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) to *pubspec.yaml*:

```
dependencies:
  meta: ^1.1.7
```

Import it in your class file:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
```

Use the `@required` annotation in your code:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person({@required this.name, this.age,});
}
```

So `name` is a required parameter, but `age` isn't.

```
final person = Person(name: 'Bob');
```

**Update:**

In an upcoming version of Dart, the `required` keyword should be added by default, so no imports will be necessary at all.

Comment: Any updates on the `required` keyword yet. I am somehow not able to find it from the docuementations.

Comment: @Sisir, It will come with the null safety update. The beta is scheduled for the end of this year and it should enter the stable channel early next year.

Comment: How is a parameter without a default not implicitly required?

Comment: @RichardHaven, currently it defaults to `null`.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2.12 with null safety you can use `required` keyword (not `@required`). Also no need to import any additional packages.

In this example named parameter `name` is optional while `effectDuration` and `recast` are required.

```
class Ability {
  final name;
  final effectDuration;
  final recast;

  Ability({this.name, required this.effectDuration, required this.recast});
}
```

Update `pubspec.yaml`, for example:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0  <3.0.0"
```

References:

1. [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)
2. [How does @required compare to the new required keyword?](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-does-required-compare-to-the-new-required-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

### With null safety:

- **Non-nullable named parameter:**

  You need to either mark the named parameter `required` or provide a default value or even mark it `late`. For example:

  ```dart
  class Foo {
    final int a;
    final int b;
    late final int c; // Mark late and provide value later.

    Foo({
      required this.a, // Mark required.
      this.b = 0, // Provided a default value.
    });
  }
  ```
- **Nullable named parameter:**

  You don't need anything special to handle them.

  ```dart
  class Foo {
    final int? z;

    Foo({
      this.z,
    });
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

If you want  declare to a empty variable but that has methods inside , you can:

1)Use the `late` keyword

2)Declare the type like possible `null` returned example: `int? number;`

3)Initialize the variable empty, for example :

```
  List listOfNumbers = [];
  Map mapOfPerson1 = {};
```

And so you can use the methods of the variable to add them values